# Gulp 4 gulp.watch not interrupting running tasks

Tags: gulp, elm

I am using `gulp.watch()` to run a task that takes typically around 2-3 min(compiling elm). It seems that the default behavior is to queue up the tasks such that if I edit a file and the task starts, and then I edit another file 30 seconds later, it will begin the task again after the current one is complete. Has anyone run into this? Is there a way to kill the running task and start it again with the new file set of changes?

Comment: Out of curiosity, approximately how many lines of code and Elm files does your project contain?

Comment: Slow compilation is a known problem in the current Elm version and there is a workaround. So maybe if you solve the deeper problem you wouldn't worry about the secondary one.

Comment: @Sidney ~370 files & ~40k lines of code.

Comment: I use webpack with webpack-dev-server, it seems that the watch mode (I believe it's part of webpack) is good about stopping the in-progress build. Although I've never tried it with multi-minute build.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I will try to make a custom one for you if you still need it.